# How stable/reliable are the boot2docker and docker-machine IP addresses?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I know that I can use `boot2docker ip` or `docker-machine ip` to get the assigned IP address of the boot2docker/docker-machine VM.

From what I understand the default IP addresses are:

- boot2docker: 192.168.59.103
- docker-machine: 192.168.99.100

Here are my questions related to this:

- Can I assume that these addresses will generally be used, unless there's a conflict with another device/VM on the same network/host?
- When stopping/starting `boot2docker` or `docker-machine` on the same machine, can I rely on the VM always using the same IP address?

I'm asking since I would like to store the environment variables created by `boot2docker shellinit` or `docker-machine env dev` in my user's profile, so I don't have to run these commands every time I start/stop the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can not rely. I've been playing around a lot with docker-machine on local with virtualbox driver, and what I noticed is that the ip addresses assigned by docker-machine depend on the order of machine start. The first started machine gets .100 (even if before it was 119).

Answer (score 1):

I've been using boot2docker for about a year. I've had the boot2docker ip set to something else a few times and couldn't tell you exactly why. If I had to guess, I'd say it was because boot2docker restarted, but some previous instance didn't die nicely and was still hogging the ip, so it went to .104 instead.

Anyway, to always be on the safe side, I just get the current boot2docker ip every time I start something new using:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=`boot2docker ip 2>/dev/null`
```

Comment: Thanks! I know that I could use `boot2docker ip` or `eval $(boot2docker shellinit)` to set the variables, but I would like to avoid having to run that every time I start boot2docker. Having these variables defined once and for all in my Bash profile would be the easiest way - hence my question...

Answer (score 0):

For me docker-machine reliably only uses the .100 IP address. However, I only ever launch one docker-machine VM at a time on that network subnet.

One idea would be to run each VM on a different host-only network subnet, so it would always be the only instance with an IP on the network and would always be .100

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "192.168.59.1/24" default
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "192.168.60.1/24" default2
```

Another idea would be to setup port forwarding on the virtual box NAT adaptor so you can always get to it from the host computer's IPs.

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natpf1 "guestssh,tcp,,2222,,22"
```

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward